# Preview Sync and Sync From Repository options not available on fresh install

Tags: crafter-cms

I have set up a fresh Crafter CMS 3.0.2 installation following the instructions [here](https://github.com/craftercms/craftercms#3-build-a-developers-environment). When I login as `admin` user I don't get `Preview Sync` and `Sync From Repository` options in the Site Config section as show in [the page here](http://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.0/site-administrators/studio/sidebar-configuration.html?highlight=sidebar#sidebar-configuration). How can I add those options for the admin user? I could not find the instructions for the same in the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sync'ing is now automatic starting version 3.0.2, see the release notes: http://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.0/release-notes/index.html

You can make updates to the underlying `git` repo, and the system will automatically pick those up.